# Giant Char or multiple Chars for console game map?

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array, char, console-application

I'm a pretty novice c++ coder and I am starting to make a console adventure game.
My adventure game currently consists of a player character that walks around inside a console application window with an 80 character width x 40 lines.

I am not sure how to approach storing the maps for my game. Each map will consist of 80 x 40 ASCII characters with colour attributes.

Should I store each 80 x 40 map in its own char? so a single map would look something like...

```
int cHeight = 5; // Reduced size for this example
int cHeight = 10; // Reduced size for this example  

// Set up the characters:

char map[cHeight][cWidth+1] = {
    "1234567890",
    "1234567890",
    "1234567890",
    "1234567890",
    "1234567890",
};

CHAR_INFO mapA[cWidth * cHeight];

for (int y = 0; y < cHeight; ++y) {                                                                 
    for (int x = 0; x < cWidth; ++x) {                                                                                                                                                                              
        mapA[x + cWidth * y].Char.AsciiChar = map[y][x];                        
        mapA[x + cWidth * y].Attributes = FOREGROUND_BLUE | Black; //I have an enum setup with background colours.          
    }
}

// Set up the positions:
COORD charBufSize = {cWidth,cHeight};
COORD characterPos = {0,0};
SMALL_RECT writeArea = {0,0,cWidth-1,cHeight-1}; 

// Write the characters:
WriteConsoleOutputA(wHnd, mapA, charBufSize, characterPos, &writeArea);
```

Im not sure if this is entirely the correct way to display the characters but I didn't think it was a good idea to just cout every character in the for loop.

So.. lets say my console window (in the above code) is 10 characters wide and 5 lines high.
In the above code I have a single map in the Char, so when loading each map I would put each one in their own array.

I was thinking of putting the entire map into a single Char, but then only displaying what I needed by offsetting the x and y in the for loop.

```
mapA[x + cWidth * y].Char.AsciiChar = map[y+offset][x+offset];
```

So the map would look more like this;

```
char map[cHeight][cWidth+1] = {
    "1234567890ABCDEFGHIJ",
    "1234567890ABCDEFGHIJ",
    "1234567890ABCDEFGHIJ",
    "1234567890ABCDEFGHIJ",
    "1234567890ABCDEFGHIJ",
};
```

with the offset I could display '1234567890' on 5 rows separately from 'ABCDEFGHIJ' on 5 rows.

So in short I would like to know the most effective way to do this, should I have multiple Chars? Should I create a class? then I could store the characters an colours? (class' are still new to me in c++).

Should I draw the terrain only in the map and then add objects (houses, trees)?
Or just draw it all in the map manually?

I think I've just thought about this too long and need a bit of direction
Thanks!

Comment: This question would much better be asked in http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/ !

Comment: Didn't even know it existed. Thanks.

Comment: I think your bigger problem is that you're thinking too much in C (or the next best procedural language). So, if this exercise is supposed to be educational, I propose that you try to do it a) without arrays b) without using raw pointers and c) without the keywords `for` and `while`. It's possible (while maybe slightly less efficient, but that shouldn't hurt in your application) and it will force you to use and learn some C++ constructs and libraries.

Comment: I'm studying this at school and only in week 5 so we haven't really touched on much at all. But I enjoy it hence why I'm doing this little side project.
I would have no idea how to accomplish anything you said.
a) how would I store the data?
b) what do you mean by raw pointers?
c) I wouldn't know where to start :)
Anywhere decent I can read up on this stuff?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way I would do it would be to create a map of

```
Node* map[height][width]
```

This means you would create the map which are pointers to Node* elements and you could define the Node* element to be...

```
class Node{
char displayCharacter;
int posx,poxy
unsigned int r;  //red
unsigned int g;  //green
unsigned int b;  //blue
unsigned int a;  //alpha
display(); // This function will know how to display a node using the colour etc
};
```

Then you could for example if you wanted to create a house you would give it the center point of the model etc... to draw to a function

```
void createHouse(Node* center)
{
    if((center->posh > 0)&&(center->posh< maxheight))
    {
        if(map[center->posy-1][center->posx]!=NULL)
        {
             map[center->posy-1][center->posx]->displayCharacter = '_';
             map[center->posy-1][center->posx]->r = 255;
        }
    }

}
```

Then in main you would have something like...

```
while(true)
{
     for(int i=0; i<maxheight; i++)
    {
        for(int j=0; j< maxwidth; j++)
        {
            map[i][j]->Display();
        }
    }

}
```

I hope all this sample code is of help to you and answered your question. I have not debugged or looked for any syntax errors. If there any errors in the code, you will have to fix them!

Good luck to you!

Comment: This has certainly given me some direction, I will most likely take this approach. Would it be worth creating each screen (80x40) for the world map in a separate node/map or create one node/map for the entire world and only display the relevant portion?

Comment: The best option would be on the program start create a world map and then as you move only display a relevant portion of the world. So for example get your players position and +- 10 up and down is what you should render/draw/display. If this has answered you question please select the tick option next to the question. Where it says 1

Comment: I'm a little confused how I am supposed to use map[h][w] if map is an uninitialised local variable? I think I misunderstand your code.